# How do I get data from differeent sheet / using sheet's name or link(GOOGLE SHEET)

Tags: google-sheets

**What I knew**

is how to link data by

1. ="SheetName!A2:B2"  (same file, Differet Sheets)
   or
2. =importrange("Url","sheetName!A2)(Different file)

all these require manual edditing

---

**My Question:**

If i have a list of these sheet name, or even it's Url,
**How can i get dates from other sheets by using these SheetName or Url?**

**BTW：**

i am trying to build a Table Menu for my Inovice system automatically
i had a file with 100+ sheet, every sheet has the same form, and i had looked up how to generate Sheetname list with url, but when i try to link (Using SheetNAme or Url as clue) to get the total sell amount/ client name / time, i counld't.

**SAMPLE**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R67knSxkHD8v6ICIYJtb24pMwV_76HoKLDb-S79lzP4/edit#gid=0

thanks for reading and helping, my english expressing may not be precise ,sorry for that.

Comment: Access is denied to yout spreadsheet, please share

Comment: If I well understand your request, use INDIRECT https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377

Comment: @MikeSteelson I have edited the access ,thank you! 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R67knSxkHD8v6ICIYJtb24pMwV_76HoKLDb-S79lzP4/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

In G8, try

```
=indirect(C8&"!C6")
```

be sure that the layout of each tab is similar (not the case in your spreadsheet) to expand the formula

Comment: it worked! thanks! (though i dont understand how it worked...)

Comment: thanks again for such a noob question!
it really helped me a lot!